# How to use GR instead of QFT (or vice versa), if possible at all, in the sense that we can use SR instead of CM even for low-speed cases?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, classical-mechanics

I asked a question on the philosophy SE - [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/91786/we-know-classical-mechanics-is-wrong-but-can-we-also-say-every-other-theory-is). However, I realized this question is better suited in a Physics SE but I would rephrase it and explain my question very precisely. First, I'll mention three remarks and then I will ask the question.

First of all, in Philosophy we say a proposition can either be correct or incorrect. In that sense, CM is not correct. Of course, it's very accurate, very relevant and very significant but it is not correct. For example, in the case of high-speed particles CM fails to give us the correct answer(to the extent we can measure) and we need to use SR. Similarly, for microscopic particles, we use QM (or some might say that even QM is wrong and we use QFT and even SR is wrong and we use GR).

Secondly, some people might argue that none of the scientific theories are correct. All are approximately correct including QFT or GR. They all have different domains of applicability. I agree with this to some extent that yes, they have different domains of applicability. However, there is a notable difference between CM and SR/GR. GR is reduced to SR in the case of flat space. SR is reduced to CM in the case of low-speed particles. But SR still works even in the case of low-speed particles, you can still use SR formula to calculate the speed of your car. CM is just a subset of SR which is itself a subset of GR. Likewise, though I haven't studied QFT, but as far as I know QFT is a superset of QM. In a non-relativistic case, QFT will be reduced to our known QM.

Thirdly, QFT and GR are two of the most accurately tested theories in Physics. We say these are correct to the extent we can measure. QFT and GR, both have their shortcomings such as there is no quantized version of GR. So, one might say QFT is still wrong because it only works in its own domain and fails to explain things where we need GR.

Now my question is, while we CAN use SR or GR instead of using CM where CM works perfectly, can we say the same thing about QFT and GR? Can we even use QFT instead of GR (doesn't matter whether it gives us accurate results) or vice versa? So for example, can we even use GR in a problem of QFT (however difficult it is)? or GR and QFT are completely designed for different purposes, and trying to replace one with the other would be using a toothbrush to perform an air strike (complete nonsense)?

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): Consider to reformulate the title. The analogies do not make much sense.

Comment: The title is reformulated. Now it's not a yes/no question.

Comment: [QFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory) incorporates principles from SR, but not GR, so no we could not recover GR from QFT because we could not recover GR from SR..

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine AdS/CFT is one instance in which we can "recover" GR from QFT.

Comment: My question can be reformulated as follows. We use the word 'unification' in the case of GR and QFT, but note that we don't use such wording in the case of CM and SR. We didn't need to unite CM and SR. If you use SR for low-speed particles, you'll automatically get the same(or extremely near) answer that you'd get using CM. Then why do use such wording in the case of QFT and GR? That's my point. 1/2

Comment: (contd.) I am saying either show me that we can analyze the same system using both GR and QFT (like we did in CM and SR), or if you can't like you said that they are meant to be used in very different aspects of nature, then QFT and GR should be given some special status than CM, SR, QM and so on. That's why I said maybe we can say that CM, SR, QM - are incorrect(and incomplete), but QFT and GR are not incorrect but only incomplete. 2/2 (can't rephrase it any better)

Comment: QFT, quantum field theory, is based on the postulates of quantum mechanics. CM SR and GR are based on space time coordinates and the particular magnitudes of the phase spaces covered, in a sense  from top down, SR emerges from GR and CM from SR. Quantum theories depend on probilities , one event has not meaning, one has to accumulate events to see the fit of the particular QFT with data. GR is not yet definitively quantized,

Comment: in the future one might have a theory where Gravity is quantized, it will include in its mathematics GR and the calculations will depend on the phase space  studied, but QFT is a modeling tool  that uses GR and SR in its mathematics.

Comment: You mean "QFT is a modeling tool that uses **QM** and SR in its mathematics", not GR and SR, right?

Comment: "I am saying either show me that we can analyze the same system using both GR and QFT (like we did in CM and SR)" Are you talking exclusively about a restricted area of CM like elastic collisions & other contact forces? What about field theories that respect SR, like classical electromagnetism or QFT itself--how would you analyze these "in CM"? It may be possible to come up with an alternate form of some field theories that respects CM, like ether theories where Maxwell's laws of electromagnetism only hold in a preferred ether frame but in other frames light has a different velocity.

Comment: (cont.) But just as this ether theory of electromagnetism can be seen as approximations to relativistic EM that have been altered to work with CM, physicists also have an approximation to GR that can work with QFT--this is known as [semiclassical gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiclassical_gravity). Likewise one can simply ignore the effect of quantum fields on spacetime curvature, and look exclusively at the effects of curvature on quantum fields, giving [quantum field theory on curved spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory_in_curved_spacetime).

Comment: (cont.) So in these ways one can deal with both GR effects and quantum field effects in the same problem, not treating them as fundamentally separate domains, though both methods require simplifying approximations (see http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.1205 for reasons to think the approximations would break down at the Planck scale). But again, it seems to me that simplifying approximations also have to be used when you try to use CM to analyze field theories that respect SR, so the argument you seem to be making for a fundamental difference between these situations doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @d_b I feel that AdS/CFT is not really what is included in QFT in this question's context, but I take the point you're making.

Comment: my next air strike will be performed with a toothbrush in honor of this question!